# How to add item to entity's 1-N property in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have entities Profile, Like and Place

Places has Likes. 
Likes has reference to place and Profile.

Place has 1-N relation on likes

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Place {

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "place")
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private transient List<Like> likes;
```

Like has reference to Profile and reference to Place

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Like implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private Profile profile;    

    @Persistent
    private Place place;
```

And profile class hasn't relations to this objects

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Profile {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private transient Key key;
```

What is the best way to add Like to Place existing place with existing profile?

I use the following code to do that:

```
    Profile profile;
    Place place;
    List<Like> likes;
    pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {   
        place = pm.getObjectById(Place.class, placeId);
        likes = place.getLikes();
        profile = pm.getObjectById(Profile.class, KeyFactory.createKey(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), login));
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }

    likes.add(new Like(place, profile));
    place.setLikes(likes);

    pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {   
        pm.makePersistent(place);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
```

and have duplicate of Profile entity. Is there way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why go to all that trouble of retrieving objects in a transaction, and then close the PM (so the objects become transient, as per the JDO spec) if you're going to add a new Like to the likes of Place? Would make way more sense to just say

```
place.getLikes().add(new Like(place, profile));
```

whilst still in the transaction. Indeed, reading about object lifecycles ought to be prerequisite to anybody using any persistence spec (JDO or JPA). Obviously the above is not specific to GAE either.

Comment: Thx! Then my problem is the following:

`Detected attempt to establish Place(1)/Like(22) as the parent of Profile("TestLike") but the entity identified by Profile("TestLike") has already been persisted without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has been persisted.`

I can't change parent of object Profile. But it hasn't any parents according JDO annotations.
Also, I need Profile and Like with the Profile to be creatable during different calls. Is it possible?

Comment: So don't persist Profile first then. When you use "GAE owned relations" you accept their problems ... of restricting what you can do. Or you make the relation "unowned" and have no restrictions (but not necessarily as efficient loading)